# javafx css multiple values on declaration

Tags: css, javafx

I am going through the various tutorials and references concerning the use of css styles.  I wish to provide a configurable css to augment the root css and I am having difficulty understanding one aspect of the caspian.css file.

It has lines such as:

```
-fx-background-color: -fx-focus-color, -fx-cell-focus-inner-border, derive(-fx-control-inner-background,-5%);
```

I can understand the derive part of it but why multiple values for the color.  How does this work?

Sorry if this is obvious to some people but I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 3):

A `Region` can have multiple background fills/images (as can be seen by looking at [`Background`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Background.html)). Each fill is drawn in order, one on top of the other, followed by the images in the same manner. If you take a look at the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region), you'll see that what you've posted is simply the CSS syntax for declaring multiple fills.

This is usually combined with setting the insets for each fill (i.e. `-fx-background-insets`) and padding (i.e. `-fx-padding`) which is how JavaFX renders "borders". Basically, the top background(s) are inset slightly which allows the bottom background(s) to show around the edges of the region. I don't remember where I read this, but I believe the reason they use this approach is because it's less expensive than using a real border.

If you're wondering why the values are `-fx-focus-color`, `-fx-cell-focus-inner-border`, et cetera, JavaFX CSS supports [looked-up colors](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor). Somewhere else in the CSS file, maybe in `.root {...}`, those values are defined and are then used throughout the style sheet. This can make it easier to use a uniform color pallet across the entire UI.

Also, note that since JavaFX 8 the default style sheet is "modena.css".

Answer (score 0):

Further reading gave me the answer. Buried in the caspian.css file is this:

```
/*******************************************************************************
 *******************************************************************************
 **                                                                           **
 ** CSS Sections for each control.  In general, each control will have a main **
 ** section that defines the following:                                       **
 **                                                                           **
 ** .control-name {                                                           **
 **     -fx-background-color: a, b, c, d                                      **
 **     -fx-background-insets: e, f, g, h                                     **
 **     -fx-background-radius: i, j, k, l                                     **
 **     -fx-padding: m                                                        **
 **     -fx-text-fill: n                                                      **
 ** }                                                                         **
 **                                                                           **
 ** where:                                                                    **
 **                                                                           **
 ** -fx-background-color, -fx-background-insets, and -fx-background-radius    **
 ** are parallel arrays that specify background colors for the control.       **
 **                                                                           **
 ** -fx-background represents a sequence of colors for regions that will be   **
 ** drawn, one on top of the other.                                           **
 **                                                                           **
 ** -fx-background-insets is a comma separated list of insets that represent  **
 ** the top right bottom left insets from the edge of the control for each    **
 ** color specified in the -fx-background-color list.  A single size for      **
 ** an inset means the same inset will be used for the top right bottom left  **
 ** values.  A negative inset will draw outside the bounds of the control.    **
 **                                                                           **
 ** -fx-background-radius is a comma separated list of values that represent  **
 ** the radii of the top right, bottom right, bottom left, and top left       **
 ** corners of the rectangle associated with the rectangle from the           **
 ** -fx-background-color list.  As with insets, a single size for a radius    **
 ** means the same radius will be used for all corners.                       **
 **                                                                           **
 ** Typically, the following values will be used:                             **
 **                                                                           **
 **    a/e/i = -fx-shadow-highlight-color, 0 0 -1 0, 5                        **
 **            Draws a background highlight dropped 1 pixel down with         **
 **            corners with a 5 pixel radius.                                 **
 **    b/f/j = -fx-outer-border, 0, 5                                         **
 **            Draws an outer border the size of the control (insets = 0) and **
 **            with corners with a 5 pixel radius.                            **
 **    c/g/k = -fx-inner-border, 1, 4                                         **
 **            Draws an inner border inset 1 pixel from the control edge and  **
 **            with corners with a smaller radius (radius = 4).               **
 **    d/h/l = -fx-body-color, 2, 3                                           **
 **            Draws the body last, inset 2 pixels from the control edge and  **
 **            with corners with an even smaller radius (radius = 3).         **
 **    m     = Padding from the edge of the control to the outer edge of the  **
 **            skin content.                                                  **
 **    n     = If specified, the color chosen for -fx-text-fill should match  **
 **            the innermost color from -fx-background-colors (e.g., 'd').    **
 **            See the -fx-text-fill entry in .scene for more information.    **
 **                                                                           **
 ** The control will also typically define pseudoclass sections for when it   **
 ** is focused, when the mouse is hovering over it ("hover") and when the     **
 ** mouse button is being held down on it (e.g., "armed").                    **
 **                                                                           **
 ** For example, in the "focused" pseudoclass, -fx-focus-color will typically **
 ** just replace -fx-shadow-highlight-color and will be drawn so it extents   **
 ** outside the control with a glowing effect.  The glowing effect is         **
 ** achieved by using a non-integer insets value of -1.4 and the radius       **
 ** is adjusted accordingly.                                                  **
 **                                                                           **
 ** .control-name:focused {                                                   **
 **     -fx-background-color: -fx-focus-color, b, c, d                        **
 **     -fx-background-insets: -1.4, f, g, h                                  **
 **     -fx-background-radius: 6.4, j, k, l                                   **
 **  }                                                                        **
 **                                                                           **
 ** In the "hover" pseudoclass, the -fx-color is replaced with -fx-hover-base **
 ** which will result in a re-derivation of the other colors in               **
 ** -fx-background-colors:                                                    **
 **                                                                           **
 ** .control-name:hover {                                                     **
 **     -fx-color: -fx-hover-base;                                            **
 ** }                                                                         **
 **                                                                           **
 ** In the "armed" pseudoclass, the -fx-color is replaced with                **
 ** -fx-pressed-base, which will result in a rederivation of the other colors **
 ** in -fx-background-colors:                                                 **
 **                                                                           **
 ** .control-name:armed {                                                     **
 **     -fx-color: -fx-pressed-base;                                          **
 ** }                                                                         **
 **                                                                           **
 ** The control will also typically include a  "disabled" pseudoclass which   **
 ** makes the component transparent:                                          **
 **                                                                           **
 ** .control-name:disabled {                                                  **
 **     -fx-opacity: -fx-disabled-opacity;                                    **
 ** }                                                                         **
 **                                                                           **
 *******************************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
```

Funny it isn't in the modena.css file